# Loop that removes vowels, adding new loop if first loop is less than 10

Tags: java, string, eclipse, loops, input

Ok, so I am creating a loop that removes all the vowels from a string until the string is equal to 10 characters (later to be 140). If the loop completes and the tweet is still greater than 10 characters, we must use another loop to continue to remove characters (except for blanks) randomly until the string is 10 characters. Right now my program runs until the first loop ends then stops without executing the other loop. How do I make it so once it is done checking for vowels it will begin to remove random numbers? I am not allowed to use (Stringbuilder,replace, etc) so forgive the code! Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TweetCompressor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = "";
        System.out.println("Type a tweet: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int f = 0;
        int tweetLengthAllowed = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < tweetLengthAllowed; i++) { 
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if(c == 'a'|| c == 'e'|| c == 'i'|| c == 'o'|| c =='u' || 
                    c == 'A' || c == 'E' ||  c == 'I' ||  c == 'O' || c == 'U') {

                f = 1;
                tweetLengthAllowed++;
            } 
            else{
                s = s += c;
                f = 0;
            }

        } 
        if(s.equals(tweetLengthAllowed) == false){
            int tweet = rand.nextInt(tweetLengthAllowed);

            String shortenedTweetA = input.substring(0, tweet);
            String shortenedTweetB = input.substring(tweet + 1);

            input = shortenedTweetA + shortenedTweetB;
            f = 0; 

        }   

        System.out.println(s);

    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what was wrong with the three answers you got when you asked this question two-and-a-half hours earlier?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace this line:

```
if(s.equals(tweetLengthAllowed) == false){
```

with:

```
if(s.length() > tweetLengthAllowed){
```

Although that doesn't give you a loop. You might instead need:

```
while(s.length() > tweetLengthAllowed){
```

and inside the loop you would need to assign the shortened string back to `s`, not to `input`.